# web3.js: Error: The method shh_newSymKey does not exist/is not available on Web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, whisper, rpc

My main goal is to call `web3.shh` functions using `RPC API` , `Web3.py` or `Web3.js`. I can call `web3.shh` functions when I use `geth attach`; which is my last option to do.

I am following this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/42983/4575).

- geth version: `1.8.0-unstable`
- I am running `geth` with `--shh` flag and `--rpcapi "admin,eth,net,web3,debug,shh"`
- `console.log(web3.version);` returns: api: `'0.20.5'`.

When I run following script:

```
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){ //web3@0.20.5
//if(!web3.eth.net.isListening().then(console.log)){ //web3@1.0.0-beta.34
    console.log("notconnected");
    process.exit();
}

var kId = web3.shh.newSymKey(); //Error occurs.
```

---

`var kId = web3.shh.newSymKey();` gives following error with `web3@'0.20.5'`:

```
Error: The method shh_newSymKey does not exist/is not available
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
    at RequestManager.send (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
    at Shh.send [as newSymKey] (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/dd.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
```

---

**Please note that I have tried it with `web3@1.0.0-beta.34` that also gives this error that seems like the same error:**

```
Promise { <pending> }
true
(node:16162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: The method shh_newSymKey does not exist/is not available
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3-shh/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
    at /home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3-shh/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:77:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/alper/eBlocBroker/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
(node:16162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16162) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this error? What do I do wrong?

*Please note* that available `shh` functions could be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/60b53e8cbe89a7357aa6cfb072f05ce6); output of `console.log(web3.shh)`.

Comment: what is your web3 version  ?

Comment: I meant your web3 version, is it web3 1.0 or 0.x because the latter doesn't have the newSymKey() method as of these docs : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3shh

Comment: Ah I am sorry I forget to add it. I did `console.log(web3.version)` and it returns: `api: '0.20.5'` @KakiMasterOfTime

Comment: like I did in your client side js you are using web3 0.x version so that method doesn't exit. you should use the newer version of web3 1.0, it is already stable.

Comment: But `web3.shh` returns the method, but when I call it it gives the error. @KakiMasterOfTime

Comment: Please see my updated answer with  try on `1.0.0-beta.34` . @KakiMasterOfTime

Comment: I tried running geth with --shh and then using web3 and it worked perfectly, but I am running the sable version of geth 1.8.7 and the latest web3 1.0. can you use the web3.shh from the javascript geth console ( `geth attach` ) ? if not try it and see if `shh` is correctly activated.

Comment: From `geth attach` ; `web3.shh.newSymKey()` works! But why it does not work through the script (that I show on my question)? @KakiMasterOfTime

Comment: From here (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-v5-RPC-API) ; I tried to use as `curl -X POST --data ...` but it also says `curl: no URL specified!`. I am not able to figure it out that how could I use it via `curl` @KakiMasterOfTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newSymKey();` function returns a promise, which needs to be resolved, to get the returned value.

This is why the error in version `web3@1.0.0-beta.34` gives you a `promise pending` message with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, and in the `web3@0.20.5` version, the error states `shh_newSymKey does not exist/is not available`. [yet]

So try `var kId = web3.shh.newSymKey().then(console.log);`

or `var kId = web3.shh.newSymKey().then(function(result) {
   console.log(result) //will log results.
})`

I prefer using the newer async / await function instead of promises (reads easier):

```
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));     

async function connect() { //note async function declaration
    if(!await web3.isConnected()){ //await web3@0.20.5
    //if(!await web3.eth.net.isListening()){ //await web3@1.0.0-beta.34
        console.log("notconnected");
        process.exit();
    }

    var kId = await web3.shh.newSymKey(); //note await
    console.log(kId);

}

connect();
```

Comment: For `shh.getPrivateKey(kId).then(console.log)` it returns: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Returned error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string`  How could I also fix this error? @Herald

Comment: I assume you posted this follow up questions here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52112/error-invalid-argument-0-json-cannot-unmarshal-object-into-go-value-of-type-s

Comment: It is caused by the same issue you had before, the line gets executed before the previous lines' promise has been resolved. So kId is empty when you call getPrivateKey. You need to use `await` as shown above, or call shh.getPrivateKey(kId); in a callback function instead of console logging the kId

the function definitions as per docs are:
            web3.shh.newSymKey([callback])
            web3.shh.getPrivateKey(id, [callback])

Comment: Instead of giving kId , I provided as a string still facing with the same error.

Comment: We can continue from the follow up question.