# Whisper Protocol: How could I use already generated keyPair or symKey after geth is restarted? Key pair cannot be stored //Error: non-existent key ID

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

My goal is to send a message from one ethereum node to another one by using same public key of the receiver. In order to accomplish it, I have followed this [guide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/51604/4575) that uses Whisper Protocol. But after `geth` on receiver is restarted its `keyPair` is lost and it says `Error: invalid id` for it when I tried to use it again.

- Please note that [Whisper Protocol Overview](http://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Overview) is out of date and `shh.newIdentity()` function does not exists anymore.

In summary approach I followed from the linked answer above that successfully works within the `geth` session:

***On the receiver node:***

```
> kId = web3.shh.newKeyPair(); //"d4a2504d22955f20156c75bfce5c7f273865f7d8976de5eed3a48a103e4e6d2d"
> web3.shh.hasKeyPair(kId) //true
> web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
    {privateKeyID:kId}, 
    function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
> web3.shh.getPublicKey(kId) //returns PUBLIC_KEY_OF_THE_RECEIVER

> stored_kId = web3.shh.addPrivateKey(shh.getPrivateKey(kId)); //"b8a8344ae7010b8453e47c31d5cb99edbc7adce5ae3fe8ece2ee90dd0bcf446c"    
> web3.shh.hasKeyPair(stored_kId) //true
```

***On the sender node:***

```
web3.shh.post({
  pubKey: 'PUBLIC_KEY_OF_THE_RECEIVER',
  ttl: 7, //Time-to-live in seconds (7 seconds).
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

---

The problem I am facing is when I restart the `geth` on the receiver node; I cannot reuse the `kId(web3.shh.newKeyPair())` that is already created on the receiver before `geth` is restarted. So I need to regenerate `shh.newKeyPair()` and share its public key with the sender all over again (which seems inefficient).

The error I am receiving after `geth` is restarted.

```
> kId ="d4a2504d22955f20156c75bfce5c7f273865f7d8976de5eed3a48a103e4e6d2d" //web3.shh.newKeyPair() that is created before geth is restarted.
> web3.shh.getPublicKey(kId)
Error: invalid id
> web3.shh.hasKeyPair(kId) //false
```

So I have to create `newKeyPair()` all over again and share its public key with the sender.

- This creates additional issue where, if receiver's `geth` node is restarted, sender's messages will not be received on receiver's end and sender will need to resent those messages into receiver with receiver's newly created public key all over again.

---

Please note that I observe similar issue on `newSymKey()`.

**Example:**

```
> shh.newSymKey()
"2d97351f0c7394679c70472b9b3a2abf3a22b6cdc9815574b103b92e1f1bfde1"
> shh.getSymKey("2d97351f0c7394679c70472b9b3a2abf3a22b6cdc9815574b103b92e1f1bfde1")
"0x1edddb4ec019ce0f31e8a4a381c9b436476b547317d9508ce9dac1fb146a65f0"
```

restart the geth node and I tried to `getSymKey()`. with already generated `symKey`:

```
> shh.getSymKey("2d97351f0c7394679c70472b9b3a2abf3a22b6cdc9815574b103b92e1f1bfde1")
Error: non-existent key ID
```

**More depth analysis:**

From: [Whisper v5 RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-v5-RPC-API#shh_addprivatekey)

> ```
> shh_addPrivateKey
>
> Stores the key pair, and returns its ID.
>
> Parameters
>
> String: private key as HEX bytes.
> Returns
>
> String: Key ID on success and an error on failure.
> ```

I have also tried `shh_addPrivateKey` to store the key pair. But after `geth` is restarted it seems like store key pair also lost and I cannot restore it.

Following line is used as the last line on the receiver node.

```
> shh.addPrivateKey(shh.getPrivateKey(kId))
"b8a8344ae7010b8453e47c31d5cb99edbc7adce5ae3fe8ece2ee90dd0bcf446c"
```

After geth is restarted still I cannot restore the keys with already added private-key's `Key ID`:

```
> kId='b8a8344ae7010b8453e47c31d5cb99edbc7adce5ae3fe8ece2ee90dd0bcf446c'
> shh.getPublicKey(kId)
Error: invalid id
> web3.shh.hasKeyPair(kId) //false
```

**[Q]** How could I handle this issue, where restoring already generated key pair (`shh.newKeyPair()` or `shh.newSymKey()`) after `geth` is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it.

After `geth` is restarted we need to call `shh.addPrivateKey()`. I guess `add` is meant for load the key pair. I was confused that I thought `shh.addPrivateKey()` was meant for save the key pairs.

```
> kId = web3.shh.newKeyPair() //create new key-pair
  "dcc9b5c6cc7110e118b45e5c6bec9b5755a02da6e57cb62a9ac1ce57e0aac41b"
> shh.getPrivateKey(kId) //Store this, it will be used on geth's new session
  "0x41a31ffc64eab3a672c408f77a82895d63623e6ccb1d08b5859f72fd6eb2e0fb"
> shh.getPublicKey(kId);   
  "0x04ed41f7ce2a44264224c34d6f2b1f9fdf00dbdb812d1e7174aec9835e80b72dc8a75113a359a8abdccac518a389c8756bb285563cb73d45abb3723c3c9c5392bc"
> web3.shh.hasKeyPair(kId) //true
> web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
    {privateKeyID:kId}, 
    function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

After `geth` restarted call `shh.addPrivateKey()` function with argument previously(before `geth` was closed) created key pair's private key:

**On Reciever:**

```
> privateKey = '0x41a31ffc64eab3a672c408f77a82895d63623e6ccb1d08b5859f72fd6eb2e0fb'; //From previous geth session
> kId=shh.addPrivateKey(privateKey) //Loads the key-pair
  "5c987a5999f3214f34c778a390e338583dd7a3b2837967158bf55af2306ea641"
> shh.hasKeyPair(kId); //true
> shh.getPublicKey(kId); //Same public key is received that is also obtained before geth is closed. 
 "0x04ed41f7ce2a44264224c34d6f2b1f9fdf00dbdb812d1e7174aec9835e80b72dc8a75113a359a8abdccac518a389c8756bb285563cb73d45abb3723c3c9c5392bc"
> web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {privateKeyID:kId}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

**On Sender:**

```
web3.shh.post({
  pubKey: '0x04ed41f7ce2a44264224c34d6f2b1f9fdf00dbdb812d1e7174aec9835e80b72dc8a75113a359a8abdccac518a389c8756bb285563cb73d45abb3723c3c9c5392bc',
  ttl: 7,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

---

- Please note that I am still working on have to retrieve messages that are sent when `geth` was closed.